# Merge two sql roes into one

Tags: sql, mysql

| ID | StartTime | StartLocation | EndTime | EndLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-15 10:00:00 | A | 2023-10-15 12:10:00 | B |
| 1 | 2023-10-15 13:00:00 | B | 2023-10-15 18:00:00 | A |

I want to merge these two rows into one so I get the first StartLocation and the last EndLocation. It should like this:

| ID | StartTime | StartLocation | EndTime | EndLocation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-15 10:00:00 | A | 2023-10-15 18:00:00 | A |

Comment: Simple aggregation. What have you researched? What is your current attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EndTime DESC) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN StartTime END) AS StartTime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN StartLocation END) AS StartLocation,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN EndTime END) AS EndTime,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN EndLocation END) AS EndLocation
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: It shouldn't depend on a fix value such as "StartLocation = 'A'"

Comment: @NewHouses I updated with another answer using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.StartTime, t1.StartLocation,
       t2.EndTime, t2.EndLocation
FROM table AS t1
JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                AND t1.EndLocation = t2.StartLocation
                AND t1.EndTime < t2.StartTime
```

If the amount of rows may be more than 2 then you'd use recursive CTE and build complete rows chain.